# Simplify a fraction of symbolic product

Tags: simplifying-expressions, products

How can I convince mathematica to simplify the ratio of these two symbolic products. You can see that the terms in the denominator are present in the numerator.

[image]

```
FullSimplify[
   Sum[((1 - pf[K[2]])/Product[ν*pf[K[1]], {K[1], 0, K[2]}])*
       Product[ν*pf[K[1]], {K[1], 0, -1 + n}], 
     {K[2], 0, -1 + n}]]
```

A simpler example would be the following,

```
Product[\[Nu]*pf[i], {i, 0, -1 + N}]/Product[\[Nu]*pf[i], {i, 0, -5 + N}]
```

Again every term in the denominator is present in the numerator. If you set N to be 9 or a specific number mathematica will expand and cancel the terms, but symbolically it cannot

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code.

Comment: When posting code, convert to `InputForm` prior to copy and paste.

Comment: I see you did that for me, thank you, and thanks for the advice

Comment: Your products are not the same. In the simpler example, i goes from -1+N in the numerator while it goes from 0 to -5+N in the numerator.

Comment: They are not meant to be the same, it's that it can be simplified to one product with a different starting index. I might be off by one, but it should be equivalent to one product from -5+N+1 to -1+N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some manually added simplification rules, Mathematica is able to simplify the expression as expected:

```
fullSimplify[args___] := FullSimplify[args,
  TransformationFunctions -> {
    Automatic, 
    ReplaceAll[
     HoldPattern[
       Product[f1_, {v1_, l1_, u1_}]^
         e1_. Product[f2_, {v2_, l2_, u2_}]^e2_.] :>
      fullSimplify /@ Unevaluated[
        Product[f1, {v1, l1, Max[l1, l2] - 1}]^e1 
         Product[f1, {v1, Min[u1, u2] + 1, u1}]^e1 
         
         Product[f1^e1 (f2 /. v2 -> v1)^e2, {v1, Max[l1, l2], 
           Min[u1, u2]}] 
         Product[f2, {v2, l2, Max[l1, l2] - 1}]^e2 
         Product[f2, {v2, Min[u1, u2] + 1, u2}]^e2
        ]
     ],
    ReplaceAll[
     Sum[s_, {v_, l_, u_}] :>
      Sum[Assuming[l <= v <= u, fullSimplify[s]], {v, l, u}]
     ]
    }
  ]

fullSimplify[
 Sum[((1 - pf[K[2]])/Product[ν*pf[K[1]], {K[1], 0, K[2]}])*
   Product[ν*pf[K[1]], {K[1], 0, -1 + n}], {K[2], 0, -1 + n}]]
```

[image]

The first additional rule effectively simplifies products of `Product`s:

$$\left(\prod_{i_1=l_1}^{u_1}f_1(i_1)\right)^{e_1}\left(\prod_{i_2=l_2}^{u_2}f_2(i_2)\right)^{e_2}$$

This can be split into a product of 5 parts: The intersecting part of the index ranges, and the four remaining parts (most of which are hopefully empty):

$$\begin{align}
&\left(\prod_{i_1=l_1}^{u_1}f_1(i_1)\right)^{e_1}\left(\prod_{i_2=l_2}^{u_2}f_2(i_2)\right)^{e_2}\\
=&\left(\prod_{i_1=l_1}^{\min(l_1,l_2)-1}f_1(i_1)\right)^{e_1}\left(\prod_{i_2=l_2}^{\min(l_1,l_2)-1}f_2(i_2)\right)^{e_2}\\
&\times\prod_{i=\max(l_1,l_2)}^{\min(u_1,u_2)}f_1(i)^{e_1}f_2(i)^{e_2}\\
&\times\left(\prod_{i_1=\max(u_1,u_2)+1}^{u_1}f_1(i_1)\right)^{e_1}\left(\prod_{i_2=\max(u_1,u_2)+1}^{u_2}f_2(i_2)\right)^{e_2}
\end{align}$$

Two subtleties: `a/b` is effectively `Times[a, Power[b, -1]]`, which is why the rule matches. And with `a_^e_.`, we also match `a` (since the `e` can be defaulted to 1).

The second rule helps with the simplification of the `Min` and `Max` expressions: We tell Mathematica that the value of the index variable inside the `Sum` will always be between the two bounds, and to simplify based on that.

Another important part is that we apply our custom simplification rules again to the individual parts of the transformed expressions, otherwise `FullSimplify` gives up to soon. So effectively we use the second rule, set `$Assumptions`, then apply the first rule to the content of the sum, simplifying the individual parts again (where now the `$Assumptions`) set in the first step help to get rid of some of the products). It is important that we map `fullSimplify` over the individual parts of the transformed product, otherwise we end up in a near-endless loop (since we can always recursively replace 2 products by 5)

Comment: The code as posted does not produce the answer shown on Mma 13.1 on Mac OS.  Is some definition not included?

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Thanks for pointing that out! That's what I get for quickly "improving" the code without testing it again... should be fixed now

Comment: This works great! Thanks for understanding the issue and implementing a solution.

I'm a bit new with mathematica, how did you learn to write this kind of function?

Comment: One issue is that I see an incorrect minus sign in front, is that a bug?

Comment: @abnowack the minus sign is correct, note how the first factor is reversed. I don't know why Mathematica decided that this is simpler though..

Answer (score 0):

In your simplified example:

```
Product[ν*pf[i], {i, 0, -1 + N}]/Product[ν*pf[i], {i, 0, -5 + N}]
```

The difficulty seems to be the unknown `pf[]` function.

If it is omitted the expression is simplified.

```
Product[ν*i, {i, 1, -1 + N}]/Product[ν*i, {i, 1, -5 + N}]
```

> (ν^4 Gamma[N])/Gamma[-4 + N]

Comment: ? Every term in the denominator product is present in the numerator. The end result should be one product with different starting and ending conditions